# cannot borrow variable as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable while building a self-referential HashMap

Tags: hashmap, rust, borrow-checker

I'm trying to build a self-referential `HashMap`:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

struct Node<'a> {
    byte: u8,
    map: HashMap<i32, &'a Node<'a>>,
}

fn main() {
    let mut network = HashMap::<u32, Node>::new();

    network.insert(0, Node { byte: 0, map: HashMap::<i32, &Node>::new() });
    network.insert(1, Node { byte: 1, map: HashMap::<i32, &Node>::new() });

    let zeroeth_node = network.get(&0).unwrap();
    let mut first_node = network.get_mut(&1).unwrap();

    first_node.map.insert(-1, zeroeth_node);
}
```

I'm running into a borrow-checker error, but I don't understand its source -- is it my method of updating the `HashMap` that is wrong, or my self-referential usage of it?

Error:

```
<anon>:15:26: 15:33 error: cannot borrow `network` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable [E0502]
<anon>:15     let mut first_node = network.get_mut(&1).unwrap();
                                   ^~~~~~~
<anon>:14:24: 14:31 note: previous borrow of `network` occurs here; the immutable borrow prevents subsequent moves or mutable borrows of `network` until the borrow ends
<anon>:14     let zeroeth_node = network.get(&0).unwrap();
                                 ^~~~~~~
<anon>:18:2: 18:2 note: previous borrow ends here
<anon>:8 fn main() {
...
<anon>:18 }
          ^
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain why it is not a duplicate of one of the [**many** questions with the same error message](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Brust%5D+cannot+borrow+also+borrowed+as+immutable). Otherwise, we risk repeating previous answers, making it harder for people to search for a solution and not telling you anything new!

Answer (score 2):

## Answer

These types of structures can be hard to make in Rust. The main thing missing from your sample is the use of [`RefCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html) which allows for shared references. `RefCell`s move Rust's borrow checking from compile-time to run-time, and thus allows you to pass around the memory location. However, don't start using `RefCell` everywhere, as it is only suitable for situations like this, and `RefCell`s will cause your program to `panic!` if you attempt to mutably borrow something while it is already mutably borrowed. This will only work with `Node`s created in `network`; you won't be able to create `Node`s that exist purely inside of a single `Node`.

## [Solution](https://is.gd/UopVrb)

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::cell::RefCell;
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Node<'a> {
    byte: u8,
    map: HashMap<i32, &'a RefCell<Node<'a>>>,
}

fn main() {
    let mut network = HashMap::new();

    network.insert(0, RefCell::new(Node { byte: 0, map: HashMap::new() }));
    network.insert(1, RefCell::new(Node { byte: 1, map: HashMap::new() }));

    let zero_node = network.get(&0).unwrap();
    zero_node.borrow_mut().byte = 2;

    let first_node = network.get(&1).unwrap();
    first_node.borrow_mut().map.insert(-1, zero_node);

    println!("{:#?}", network);
}
```